# Homecook diet for dogs: should I add vitamins?

Tags: dogs, diet

I'm currently feeding my dog a mix of dry food (morning) and various kinds of homecook stews (evening).

I'm wondering if there is some natural ingredient that would be beneficial for the dog, like added vitamins. I'm thinking about adding some orange juice for example.

Do they need vitamins the same way as we do?

Comment: Why cook the food (meat I assume), feed it raw and it's much better for the dogs

Comment: If you really want a healthy dog, I would suggest you do a lot of research on raw diet for a dog. You can draw some conclusions after your research and the decision to switch or not is yours. However, just make sure you do enough research or consult a raw diet expert so you won't be surprised in any way in the switching process.

Answer (score 1):

I homecook (and meal prep) for my dog, who seems to really like the variety. I do give her a VetIQ [Canine Multivitamin (Sam's Club)](https://www.samsclub.com/sams/multivitamin-180-ct-22-2-oz-soft-chews/prod21428063.ip?xid=plp_product_1_1) to make sure I don't miss giving her something nutritionally vital.

One of the primary concerns about homecooked foods is providing enough calcium. You can solve this with the multivitamin, or by crushing dried egg shells (in a clean coffee grinder), or providing a "Tums" antacid tablet. And cottage cheese is always a welcomed treat.

The biggest problem I have is giving enough (but not too many) calories throughout the day. Too many treats has meant a 1.5 pound increase - so now we are on a diet. Whick oddly enough is worse for me than for her.